# CASE statement not working as it should in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, case

```
SELECT  userid,                                                                                         
  (SELECT CASE WHEN (COUNT(CASE WHEN casinowagers != 0
          THEN 1
            ELSE null
          END)
                + COUNT(CASE WHEN depositmade_amt != 0
                        THEN 1
                            ELSE null
                        END)) >= 3  
        AND (Round(sum(totalhold - playercomps - freemoney - (depositmade_amt*.1)),2)) >= 10
                THEN "VIP"
                    ELSE "NON-VIP"
                END as VIPcheck 
    FROM player_activity        
    WHERE YEAR(txndate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
        AND MONTH(txndate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)         
    ) as vipMonthStatus,            
    (COUNT(CASE WHEN casinowagers != 0
            THEN 1
            ELSE null
            END) 
                + COUNT(CASE WHEN depositmade_amt != 0
                        THEN 1
                            ELSE null
                        END)) as activityCount, 
    (Round(sum(totalhold - playercomps - freemoney - (depositmade_amt*.1)),2)) as Value,                        
FROM player_activity
WHERE userid = 2023410 
GROUP BY year(txndate),month(txndate)  
LIMIT 1000
```

So basically the vipMonth status is always returning as "VIP". However, for the month of May (because of the below "where" statement), it should be "non-vip" because only 1 deposit and 1 wager were made.

What gives?

```
( WHERE YEAR(txndate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
        AND MONTH(txndate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) )
```

Comment: I am guessing you also need `WHERE userid = 2023410` in that subquery (or to correlate it with an equivalent WHERE).

Answer (score 0):

You need to tie the player_activity table in the vipMonthStatus subquery to the player_activity table in the main query.

First alias the "inner" player_activity and the "outer" player_activity tables so that you can tell them apart. Something like in_player_activity and out_player_activity.

Then you need to add an additional WHERE statement to the vipMonthStatus subquery to restrict the records in the inner table to the associated records in the outer table based on userid . It would end up looking like this:

```
FROM player_activity in_player_activity     
WHERE YEAR(in_player_activity.txndate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
    AND MONTH(in_player_activity.txndate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)  
    AND in_player_activity.userid = out_player_activity.userid
```

Keep in mind now that you have introduced table aliases, you will need to add the alias prefix to all of the other column names. Personally I would use something more concise like opa and ipa.